# Bind menu event handlers in another module in wxPython

Tags: python, class, wxpython

I'm building a menu for a frame with wxPython (python3).
I want to separate the main.py from the menus.py - have these two separated files so the code is organized into smaller pieces.

I need to be able to pass control back to the main.py from menus.py.
In particular, I need that the handlers for the events I bind for menu items (in menus.py) will reside in main.py, or, alternatively, have the handlers in menus.py, but reference objects in main.py (for example, to Close() the application for the "Exit" menu item.

This is what I have so far, and I tried both ways with no success. How is this achieved?

**main.py**

```
import wx
import menus

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "My App Title", size=(1200, 800))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        mainMenu = menus.MainMenu()
        mainMenu.build_main_menu(self)


    def onExit(self):
        self.Close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**menus.py**

```
from wx import Menu, MenuBar, MenuEvent, MenuItem, Frame, EVT_MENU

class MainMenu(object):
    def build_main_menu(self, frame):

        self.fileMenu = Menu()
        exitMenuItem = self.fileMenu.Append(101, "E&xit", "Close the application")


        menuBar = MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, "&File")
        frame.Bind(EVT_MENU, MainFrame.onExit(frame), exitMenuItem)
        frame.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        return self
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, but just not quite there. For this sort of thing, there is no need to wrap the menu creation code inside a class, so I changed that to just a function. Here's `menu.py`:

```
from wx import Menu, MenuBar, MenuEvent, MenuItem, Frame, EVT_MENU


def build_main_menu(frame):

    fileMenu = Menu()
    exitMenuItem = fileMenu.Append(101, "E&xit", "Close the application")

    menuBar = MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
    frame.Bind(EVT_MENU, frame.onExit, exitMenuItem)
    frame.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
```

Note that you need to call the `onExit` using the `frame` instance, not by trying to call it via a class (`MainFrame`) that you haven't even imported. Also you do **not** call an event handler in the bind operation. It will get called when the button is pressed.

Next I updated your `main.py`:

```
import wx
import menus

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "My App Title", size=(1200, 800))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        mainMenu = menus.build_main_menu(self)

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

There are two changes here. First we don't need to create an instance of the menu module's class as there is no class any longer. Secondly event handlers take two arguments: `self` and `event`.

Now it works!

Comment: Thank you, Mike! Just to know for other situations: could it not be done between two classes?

Comment: Oh that would have worked too. Just put that working code back into the class and it should work. The problem was the way you were binding the event handler, not the class. I just decided to make the code simpler at the same time.